# Delete elements of list appearing before one element and itself with R

Tags: r, list

I have a list of elements (letter here in the example)

```
 (l <- list(letters[1:2], letters[2:3]))

# [[1]]    
# [1] "a" "b"    
# [[2]]   
# [1] "b" "c" 

And another elements 
(r <- letters[2])

# [1] "b"
```

I create a function that delete that  elements appearing before one element and itself (here "b").

```
out = lapply(l, function(x) x[-c(1,which(x == "b"))])
Filter(length, out)

#[[1]]

#[1] "c"
```

Now my question is in case I have a list of elements r not only one "b", how can I loop all the list:

```
for example :
```

> r

```
[1] a
[2] b
```

I would like to have a result like this 
   [1] c

Thank you

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `%in%`

```
 Filter(length, lapply(l, function(x) 
             x[-seq(tail(which(x %in% r),1))]))
 #[[1]]
 #[1] "c"
```

#### data

```
r <- c('a', 'b')
```

Comment: thank you akrun, I get this > Filter(length,lapply(l, function(x) x[-which(x %in% r)]))
 ##  list()

Comment: @Fish Do you have `r` as a `vector` or `list`?

Comment: I still have a problem related to this . I create a new post here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35941648/create-list-by-deleting-elements-of-list-appearing-before-one-element-and-itself